# check duplicate in multiple columns in very big data sheet with Excel Vba

Tags: sorting, duplicates, autofilter

i was trying to catch duplicates in a range of six columns and update main datasheet if any duplicates found. I have tried to automate in creating criteria like years, product class etc from the main datasheet. It does not work. It just cause the computer to freez excel and out of memory message box pops up. any solutions?

```
    Sub DuplicateChecker()
    
    With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
                .EnableEvents = False
                .DisplayAlerts = False
        End With
    
    
    Dim LROW As Long, lRow1 As Long, LroW2 As Long, i As Long
    Dim Wbk As Workbook
    Dim TrNg1 As Range, tRNg2 As Range, trNG3 As Range, tRNG4 As Range, TRnG5 As Range, Trng6 As Range
    Dim wHsH As Worksheet, WhSh1 As Worksheet, wHSH2 As Worksheet, SH As Worksheet, R As Range, oCel As Range, CEL As Range, mRng1 As Range, MrnG2 As Range, mRNg As Range
    
    
    Set Wbk = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wHsH = Wbk.Sheets("FINALSHEET")
    Set WhSh1 = Sheets.Add
    Set SH = Sheets.Add
       ' get list of years as criteria from the main sheet
    
    With wHsH
            LROW = .Range("A" & .rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
            wHsH.Range("M1:M" & LROW).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, copytorange:=wHsH.Range("Q1"), Unique:=True
            lRow1 = .Range("Q" & .rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
            Set mRng1 = .Range("Q2:Q" & lRow1)
          
          For Each CEL In mRng1
            If CEL <> "" Then
                WhSh1.Cells.Clear
                wHsH.Range("A1:O" & LROW).AutoFilter FIELD:=13, criteria1:=CEL.Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues
                wHsH.Range("A1:O" & LROW).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy WhSh1.Range("A1")
                wHsH.AutoFilterMode = False
                    
   ' get product class list to be used as criteria

                    With WhSh1
                        LroW2 = .Range("A" & .rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
                        wHsH.Range("S:S").Clear
                        WhSh1.Range("A1:A" & LroW2).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, copytorange:=wHsH.Range("S1"), Unique:=True
                        wHsH.Range("S1").Value = CEL.Value
                        lRow1 = wHsH.Range("Q" & .rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
                        Set MrnG2 = wHsH.Range("S2:S" & lRow1)
                         ' separate data by product class and screen duplicates in 6 columns 

                        For Each oCel In MrnG2
                            If oCel.Value <> "" Then
                                SH.Cells.Clear
                                WhSh1.Range("A1:O" & LroW2).AutoFilter FIELD:=1, criteria1:=CEL.Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues
                                WhSh1.Range("A1:O" & LroW2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy SH.Range("A1")
                                WhSh1.AutoFilterMode = False
                                    With SH
                                    LROW = .Range("A" & .rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
                                    
                                    If LROW > 2 Then
                                    
                                    
                                    Set mRNg = SH.Range("A2:O" & LROW)
                          
                                         Set TrNg1 = SH.Range("A2:A" & LROW)
                                         Set tRNg2 = SH.Range("J2:J" & LROW)
                                         Set trNG3 = SH.Range("K2:K" & LROW)
                                         Set tRNG4 = SH.Range("L2:L" & LROW)
                                         Set TRnG5 = SH.Range("M2:M" & LROW)
                                         Set Trng6 = SH.Range("N2:N" & LROW)
                                        
                            i = 1
                          For Each R In mRNg
                            If R.Value <> "" Then
                                 If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(TrNg1, R.Offset(i - 1, 1).Value) > 1 Then
                                    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(tRNg2, R.Offset(i - 1, 10).Value) > 1 Then
                                        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(trNG3, R.Offset(i - 1, 11).Value) > 1 Then
                                            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(tRNG4, R.Offset(i - 1, 12).Value) > 1 Then
                                                If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(TRnG5, R.Offset(i - 1, 13).Value) > 1 Then
                                                    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Trng6, R.Offset(i - 1, 14).Value) > 1 Then
                                                       wHsH.Range("A1:O" & .rows.Count).End(xlUp).AutoFilter FIELD:=1, criteria1:=oCel.Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues
                                                       wHsH.Range("A1:O" & .rows.Count).End(xlUp).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
                                                       wHsH.AutoFilterMode = False
                                                    End If
                                                End If
                                            End If
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                          i = i + 1
                        Next R
                        End If
                       End With
                       End If
                       Next oCel
                       End With
                       End If
                       Next CEL
                
                
                End With
                
        
    
    With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
                .EnableEvents = True
                .DisplayAlerts = True
        End With
    
    
    End Sub
```